# Accessing specific data from JSON data (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to JSON in Python (forgive me if I word something incorrectly) and I am trying to parse JSON information I get from an API. I get the API information successfully, but when I attempt to extract the information that I need (specifically the 'name' value in the variable info). I can't seem to find anything on how to access it. The code is below:

```
# Importing JSON handling library for parsing GET request using requests library
import json
import requests
import ast
import collections

# API Endpoint
url = "https://fnbr.co/api/shop"

# API key
key = "" # key is usually here

# Defining Parameters
headers = {"x-api-key":key}

# Sending GET request
req = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers)



info = req.json()
info = info['data']['featured']
print(info)
```

And the output:

```
[{'id': '5e8743597576ec53deb18eeb', 'name': 'Deadpool Gear Bundle', 'price': '2,000', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/bundle/5e8743597576ec53deb18eeb/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': False, 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'bundle', 'slug': 'deadpool-gear-bundle', 'readableType': 'Bundle', 'description': False, 'bundleSet': '5e87444f7576ec029cb18eef', 'bannerText': False, 'history': {'occurrences': 4, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-05T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-04T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z']}}, {'id': '5e8fbb5d3cdac627afdebeb5', 'name': 'Deadpool Mashups', 'price': '2,000', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/bundle/5e8fbb5d3cdac627afdebeb5/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': False}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'bundle', 'slug': 'deadpool-mashups', 'readableType': 'Bundle', 'description': 'Outfit Bundle.', 'bundleSet': '5e8fba7a3cdac6863bdebeaf', 'bannerText': False, 'history': {'occurrences': 1, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z']}}, {'id': '5e8742117576ec88f6b18ee0', 'name': 'Chimichanga!', 'price': '300', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/emote/5e8742117576ec88f6b18ee0/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': False, 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'emote', 'slug': 'chimichanga', 'readableType': 'Emote', 'description': 'Too hot! Too hot!', 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': 'Collect the Set!', 'history': {'occurrences': 4, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-05T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-04T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z']}}, {'id': '5e8741f37576ecfc79b18edd', 'name': "Scootin'", 'price': '500', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/emote/5e8741f37576ecfc79b18edd/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': False, 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'emote', 'slug': 'scootin', 'readableType': 'Emote', 'description': 'Dangerously dainty.', 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': False, 'history': {'occurrences': 4, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-05T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-04T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z']}}, {'id': '5e87422b7576ec21f5b18ee3', 'name': 'Dragacorn', 'price': '1,500', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/glider/5e87422b7576ec21f5b18ee3/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': False, 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'glider', 'slug': 'dragacorn', 'readableType': 'Glider', 'description': 'Bask in its mutant rainbow glory.', 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': 'Collect the Set!', 'history': {'occurrences': 4, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-05T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-04T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z']}}, {'id': '5e8fbafd3cdac6ed02debeb3', 'name': 'Cuddlepool', 'price': '1,500', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5e8fbafd3cdac6ed02debeb3/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': 'https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5e8fbafd3cdac6ed02debeb3/featured.png', 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'outfit', 'slug': 'cuddlepool', 'readableType': 'Outfit', 'description': 'Ferociously furry.', 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': False, 'history': {'occurrences': 1, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z']}}, {'id': '5e8fb9f33cdac69b0fdebead', 'name': 'Ravenpool', 'price': '1,500', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5e8fb9f33cdac69b0fdebead/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': 'https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5e8fb9f33cdac69b0fdebead/featured.png', 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'outfit', 'slug': 'ravenpool', 'readableType': 'Outfit', 'description': 'Maximum darkness.', 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': False, 'history': {'occurrences': 1, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z']}}, {'id': '5e8741d67576ecad85b18eda', 'name': 'Meaty Mallets', 'price': '800', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/pickaxe/5e8741d67576ecad85b18eda/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': False, 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'marvel', 'type': 'pickaxe', 'slug': 'meaty-mallets', 'readableType': 'Pickaxe', 'description': "Give 'em a thwack.", 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': 'Collect the Set!', 'history': {'occurrences': 4, 'firstSeen': '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-05T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-04T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-04-03T00:00:00.471Z']}}, {'id': '5db7ff1ac02d0515d20b054c', 'name': 'Riley', 'price': '1,200', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5db7ff1ac02d0515d20b054c/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': 'https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5db7ff1ac02d0515d20b054c/featured.png', 'resizeAvailable': True}, 'rarity': 'rare', 'type': 'outfit', 'slug': 'riley', 'readableType': 'Outfit', 'description': 'The city is her playground.', 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': False, 'history': {'occurrences': 5, 'firstSeen': '2019-11-27T00:00:00.000Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2019-11-27T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-03-09T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-02-06T00:00:00.575Z']}}, {'id': '5db804ebc02d05322e0b059d', 'name': 'Wild X', 'price': '300', 'priceIcon': 'vbucks', 'priceIconLink': 'https://image.fnbr.co/price/icon_vbucks.png', 'images': {'icon': 'https://image.fnbr.co/wrap/5db804ebc02d05322e0b059d/icon.png', 'png': False, 'gallery': False, 'featured': 'https://image.fnbr.co/wrap/5db804ebc02d05322e0b059d/featured.png'}, 'rarity': 'uncommon', 'type': 'wrap', 'slug': 'wild-x', 'readableType': 'Wrap', 'description': 'Show your style.', 'bundleSet': False, 'bannerText': 'Collect the Set!', 'history': {'occurrences': 5, 'firstSeen': '2019-11-27T00:00:00.000Z', 'lastSeen': '2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'dates': ['2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2019-11-27T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-03-09T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-02-06T00:00:00.575Z']}}]
```

I need specifically all of the 'name' value attributes, such as 'Deadpool Gear Bundle', but I'm unsure how. If I try accessing the location info['data']['featured']['name'] location it gives me an error. Also, there could be a different amount of 'name' values every day, so I need a method that returns the attributes of all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there's 2 types of objects you need to be aware of.

**dict**: when you load JSON it's stored as a dictionary object. Dict objects let you access the values through keys, like you're doing here -> info['data']['featured']

**list**: print(info) is showing that 'info' is a list of things. You can tell by the square brackets [], or just by calling `print(type(info))`. A list is ordered so to access the name for the first object in your list you would say `info[0]['name']`.

To get all the objects in your list in a row you can use a for loop:

`for x in info:
    print(x['name'])`

You can name 'x' whatever you want. That loop is just saying " for every object in this list, perform the following action"

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I tried this and it gives me a TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Nevermind, I was being dumb. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!